# VLC has gone over the top left of the screen. How do I move it?

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, window-manager, off-screen

I started VLC the other day, and it is starting off the top left corner of the screen, so as I can't select the title bar to move.

I've tried right clicking it's entry in the task bar, and selecting move, and that didn't work either. How do I get it back into the screen?

EDIT: This is on Vista btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very weird for the "move" not to work. Did you just try with the mouse?

This probably would've failed as you have to click (and drag) on the title bar or very few other areas that may also be hidden.

Try to do "move again" and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> on the Keyboard and see if you can move it that way.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried with the mouse.

Comment: In case anyone else has problems... You can use just the → & ↓ keys to move a few pixels, but adding Shift budges it about 5 or 10 at a time.

Comment: On *Ubuntu*, I have been able to move vlc interface again after I have found where vlcrc is using command `find / -name "*vlcrc*"` and removed both files (`vlcrc` + `vlc-qt-interface`).

Answer (score 14):

May be by following the advice in the "[Bring Misplaced Off-Screen Windows Back to Your Desktop (Keyboard Trick)](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/bring-misplaced-off-screen-windows-back-to-your-desktop-keyboard-trick/)"

> First make sure you’ve alt-tabbed to the window, or clicked on it once to bring it into focus. Then right-click on the taskbar and choose Move
>
> At this point, you should notice that your cursor changes to the “Move” cursor, but you still can’t move anything.
>
> Just hit any one of the arrow keys (Left, Right, Down, Up), move your mouse, and the window should magically “pop” back onto the screen.
>
> Note: For keyboard savvy people, you can jus:
>
> - <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to the window,
> - use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then
> - <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>Arrow</kbd> key, and then
> - move your mouse.

As [Liam Mitchell](https://superuser.com/users/386163/liam-mitchell) adds [in the comments](https://superuser.com/questions/44290/vlc-has-gone-over-the-top-left-of-the-screen-how-do-i-move-it/44293?noredirect=1#comment2349888_44293)

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> to maximize then drag title bar down fixed it.

Comment: Alt+Space X to maximize then drag title bar down fixed it.

Comment: @LiamMitchell Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @LiamMitchell thank you! Your comment deserves its own response)

Answer (score 4):

<sub>From an anonymous user:</sub>

But actually there is an easier working solution in the [VideoLAN Forum](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=85063):

Removal of the directory %appdata%\vlc helps.
I removed the folder and it rebuilt what it needed when it started it up again
It seem to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

here's one mighty little tool for you:

**[AltMove Windows & Mouse Manager](http://www.deskex.com/Altmove/index.asp)** adds more functionality to your mouse for interacting with windows.

> The moving: **You can move windows and
>   controls which do not support this
>   ability.**
>
> The resizing: **You can resize windows
>   and controls which do not support this
>   ability.**
>
> The hiding and restoring: You can hide
>   any window from desktop (to tray bar
>   or completely) and restore it.
>
> The opaque: You can change the opaque of
>   windows.
>
> The document work: You can assign
>   key-mouse combinations to standard menu
>   items of different programs.
>
> Start your programs: Use the mouse to run
>   your programs and open documents from
>   evevrywhere.

*AltMove is freeware.*

Answer (score 2):

Windows Vista / 7 solution:

1. Press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, "connect display" then "duplicate". This should bring the VLC window back to your screen.
2. Close VLC player and press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> again, now "disconnect display" and choose "disconnect projector".
3. Problem solved. VLC will work properly next time you launch it.

Comment: Thanks! :) Although step 1 didn't bring VLC back to my screen, after having done steps 2 and 3, VLC appeared back on my screen. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is sort of a non-answer answer.

I spent about an hour looking around the registry and the %appdata%\roaming\vlc folder in windows, and wherever this setting is, it is *very* nicely hidden.  You'd expect to find it in the vlcrc or vlc-qt-interface file, but I sure don't see it.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I have been able to move vlc interface again after I have found where vlcrc is using command `find / -name "*vlcrc*"` and removed both files (`vlcrc` + `vlc-qt-interface`).

Answer (score 0):

You could always download vlc again, and run the 'reset preferences'-file that comes with it.

Comment: Isn't that a bit overkill?